# RadAutoCompleteTextView does not have exposed events for DisplayMode = Plain

Tags: nativescript

RadAutoCompleteTextView does not have exposed events for DisplayMode = "Plain". Like when we used DisplayMode = "Token" then tokenRemoved works. But when we used  DisplayMode = "Plain" that time what should i do?

[Text](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=G78alI&v=179)

Comment: Use `textChanged` event to listen to text changes when mode is plain.

Comment: I have already check that. But textChanged fires multiple times. 

And when i take a flag after didAutoComplete event fires that time also textChanged fired twice.

Comment: Yes, it would be triggered for every key up and that's how Plain mode works. There are no Tokens in Plain mode, it's just plain text.

Comment: Yes. But Finally i got solution. 
In Design i have use properties "ShowCloseButton=false" and create my own close button. And its fullfill my requirement. Because i have requirement few validation in close button.

Answer (score 0):

In Design i have use properties "ShowCloseButton=false" and create my own close button. And its fullfill my requirement. Because i have requirement few validation in close button.